# error in getting value from input that have ngIf directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I get an exception `Error TypeError and Error Context` when the submit button is clicked. If I will delete the `ngIf` directive It will work as excepted, The Full StackTrace:

```
PlayerNameFormComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (PlayerNameFormComponent.html:8)
at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
at eval (core.js:12301)
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:4343)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
```

**PlayerNameFormComponent.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(firstPlayer.value, secondPlayer.value)"> // The line that throws the exception

  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <label for="firstPlayer">First Player Name</label>
    <input #firstPlayer id="firstPlayer" name="firstPlayer" type="text" class="validate">
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="isMultiplePlayers" class="input-field col s6">
    <label for="secondPlayer">Second Player Name</label>
    <input #secondPlayer id="secondPlayer" name="secondPlayer" type="text" class="validate">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Start</button>
</form>
```

**PlayerNameFormComponent.ts**

```
export class PlayerNameFormComponent {
  isMultiplePlayers = true;

 public onSubmit(firstPlayer: string, secondPlayer: string) {
   console.log(firstPlayer);
   console.log(secondPlayer);
 }

}
```

**EDIT:**
I changed my form tag to - `<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(firstPlayer?.value, secondPlayer?.value)">` and now its print to console the firstPlayer input value and instead of secondPlayer value its prints `null`

Thanks for any kind of help :)

Comment: can we see what you do on submit?

Comment: `firstPlayer` or `secondPlayer` is probably `undefined` I would double check where you set those and make sure that's going smoothly

Comment: @Farasi78 see my edit please

Comment: How about adding default value to your input?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I tried to add default value the secondPlayer The value is still null inside onSubmit() function

Comment: Then  try [ngModel]

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina Its not work, but If I remove the ngIf it's work as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template reference variables can be accessed anywhere in template, so the docs state clearly. **[This article](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/05/use-angular-template-reference-variables-anywhere-in-the-template-not.html)** is very helpful to understand what happens with structular directives, in this case your `*ngIf`.

What happens with the `*ngIf` is that it creates it's own template, so your template reference is accessible inside the template, the template created by `*ngIf` and only in that scope.

Here's excerpt from the website:

> Sample code that throws error:
>
> ```
> <div *ngIf="true">
>   <my-component #variable [input]="'Do you see me?'>
> </div>
> {{ variable.input }}
> ```
>
> The reason for this is the ngIf directive - or any other directive used together with a star (*). These directives are so called structural directives and the star is just a short form for something more complex. Every time you use a structural directive (ngIf, ngFor, ngSwitchCase, ...) Angular's view engine is desugaring (it removes the syntactical sugar) the star within two steps to the following final form (using the previous ngIf as an example):
>
> ```
> <ng-template [ngIf]="true">
> ...
> </ng-template>`
> ```
>
> Did you notice? Something extraordinary emerged out of the previous HTML containing the structural directive - the ng-template node. This node is the reason for limiting the scope of the template reference variable to exactly this inner DOM part only - it defines a new template inside. Because of limiting a variable to its defining template any variable defined within the ng-template (and this means within the DOM part of the ngIf) cannot be used outside of it. It cannot cross the borders of a template.

---

But how to solve your underlying problem, i.e getting the values... You almost have a template-driven form set up already, so you could do that, or then go the reactive way :)

Comment: I mark this answer as the right answer because of the great explanation of what is going on under the hoods

Answer (score 4):

Your problem doesn't come from your `*ngIf`. Try to remove temporary the error, using Elvis operator:

```
onSubmit(firstPlayer?.value, secondPlayer?.value)
```

Or you can make sure into your onSubmit that the HTML element firstPlayer and secondePlayer return HTMLObject.

Into your component, do this:

```
onSubmit(firstPlayer, secondPlayer) {
   console.log(firstPlayer, secondPlayer);
}
```

And into your HTML template, change the `(ngSubmit)` line with:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(firstPlayer, secondPlayer)">
```

If the result is correction you get ...

```
<input id="firstPlayer" name="firstPlayer" type="text" class="validate">
...
```

... into the console.

If it is really undefined, use `[ngModel]="firstPlayer"` and check if the error still occurs.

Comment: See my edit please , the first player work as expected but the secondPlayer is null/undefined depends on what I am sending to onSubmit() the value or the html tag

Answer (score 0):

You can also just the line as given below to get it working if you don't want to go to the reactive forms approach as pointed by @AT82.

```
<div *ngIf="isMultiplePlayers" class="input-field col s6">
```

to

```
<div [hidden]="isMultiplePlayers" class="input-field col s6">
```

Try to avoid *(star) directives which cause these errors due to structural changes they do in the DOM.